# how to write a blank column with CSVPrinter of apache.commons.csv

Tags: java, apache, csv, export-to-csv

I am using CSVPrinter in order to read and write CSV. While writing CSV,
I want to write a blank column such like that "x",,"y" (the second column). But unfortunately it writes as "x","","y". How I can write a blank column by using CSVPrinter? I used following stuff in order to write it . Even, I could not find it in the CSVPrinter documentation. Please help me.

printer.print(null)  -> ""
printer.print("") -> ""

Thanks

Comment: Please post the CSVFormat you are using. Default output is different.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are looking for was added only in version 1.5:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

With this API you can apply ALL_NON_NULL quote mode:

```
    CSVFormat customFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
            .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL_NON_NULL);

    CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(System.out, customFormat);
    printer.print("x");
    printer.print("");
    printer.print(null);
    printer.print("y");
    printer.println();
```

Output:

```
"x","",,"y"
```